# Python: test function changes value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have the list:

```
DATA = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
        [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
        [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
        [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]
```

In a test_function i change 1 number of this list:

```
def test_check_value(self):
        DATA[1][3] = 7...
```

(I do this in multiple functions with other numbers)

At the end my whole list have changed. What can I do so that the functions just test it (with the changed value) and dont change the value of my main list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `copy.deepcopy` at the beginning of each test

```
>>> import copy
>>> l1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> l2 = copy.deepcopy(l1)
>>> l2[0][0] = 9
>>> l2
[[9, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> l1
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Note that it works well because you keep integers inside the nested list. If it was some modifiable data structure, `deepcopy` would create new instances.

Answer (score 1):

You could locally copy the list, to do this you can use the [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function.

```
import copy

def test_check_value(self):
    local_list = copy.deepcopy(DATA)
    local_list[1] = 0
```

---

I think interesting to note that using *the built-in `list()` function to copy does not work for nested lists*, so in this case `copy.deepcopy` has to be used.
Thanks @Bartosz Marcinkowski  for pointing that out.

For further information on lists copies, see http://stackoverflow.com./a/2612815/2549230

Comment: Does not work in OP case. You need deepcopy to make it work for nested lists.

Comment: I missed it, thanks for pointing out. I'll edit it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have defined your list as **global**.thus for get ride of this situation you need to pass a copy of your list to your function , you can use `[a[:] for a in DATA]` to copy your nested list or use `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
my_list=[a[:] for a in DATA]
def test_check_value(self,my_list):
```

Comment: Does not work in OP case.  The copy contains references to lists nested in the global.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski yep, i miss that its a nested list, fixed!